# Is it possible to disable Django two-factor authentication with a setting?

Tags: django, selenium, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to write a [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) for a website which is protected with [Django Two-Factor Authentication](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). What I have so far is:

```
import os
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from lucy_web.test_factories import UserFactory

from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(settings.BASE_DIR)), 'chromedriver')
assert os.path.isfile(chromedriver_path), f"There should be a chromedriver executable at {chromedriver_path}"


class SeleniumTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
        cls.password = 'foobar'         # Set the password here to avoid using the hashed attribute
        cls.user = UserFactory(password=cls.password, is_superuser=True)

    def test_login(self):
        url = urljoin(self.live_server_url, reverse('dashboard:families'))
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('auth-username').send_keys(self.user.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('auth-password').send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Next"]').click()
```

The problem is that at this point, the driver arrives at a two-factor authentication login page in which it is required to scan a QR code:

[image]

This is too involved to do using the test browser, so I'd like to use [`override_settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) to disable the two-factor authentication for testing purposes. However, looking at the [General Settings](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#general-settings) of Django two-factor authentication, I wasn't able to find a setting which disables it.

Is there any way I could disable two-factor authentication to continue with this live server test case?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality to do this, but you can easily accomplish it by extending the middleware. Just swap "OTPMiddleware" in your settings with the full dotted path to this one, and change DEBUG to some other variable if you like.

```
from django_otp import DEVICE_ID_SESSION_KEY, _user_is_authenticated
from django_otp.models import Device
from django_otp.middleware import OTPMiddleware, is_verified
from django.conf import settings
class ToggleableOTPMiddleware(OTPMiddleware):
    def _verify_user(self, request, user):
        """
        Sets OTP-related fields on an authenticated user.
        """
        user.otp_device = None

        # START CHANGE
        if settings.DEBUG:
            user.is_verified = lambda: True
        else:
            user.is_verified = functools.partial(is_verified, user)
        # END CHANGE

        if _user_is_authenticated(user):
            persistent_id = request.session.get(DEVICE_ID_SESSION_KEY)
            device = self._device_from_persistent_id(persistent_id) if persistent_id else None

            if (device is not None) and (device.user_id != user.id):
                device = None

            if (device is None) and (DEVICE_ID_SESSION_KEY in request.session):
                del request.session[DEVICE_ID_SESSION_KEY]

            user.otp_device = device

        return user
```

Comment: Ideally, I would not like to change the code base just to accommodate testing, because this introduces the possibility of new bugs. In this particular instance, is there perhaps a way to generate a valid token as a test fixture?